# Part of my table is not placed in the pdf output

Tags: tables

I used this code using an online website : [here](http://truben.no/table/) to create my table, my first problem is that it can not merge the first row, then also I couldn't design it the way you see in the image attached ,is such an edit possible ?[image]

```
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
       Naive Constant Design Model & ~                             & ~    & ~       & ~      & ~       & ~       \\ \hline
       Ntrneq                      & ynaive                        & Nw00 &  Ndof00 &  SSE00 &  MSE00  &  MSE00a \\ \hline
       2217                        & [-1.7609  0.132   1.1581]e-14 &   3  &  3162   &  3162  &  0.9991 & 1       \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merging columns is done with `\multicolumn`

You need to add a `\caption` for an auto numbered title.

Thicker borders can be achieved with the `tabu` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{tabu}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabu}{|[1.5pt]c|*{5}{c|}c|[1.5pt]}
            \tabucline[1.5pt]{-}
            \multicolumn{7}{|[1.5pt]c|[1.5pt]}{\textbf{Naive Constant Design Model}} \\ \tabucline[1.5pt]{-}
            Ntrneq & ynaive & Nw00 & Ndof00 & SSE00 & MSE00 & MSE00a \\ \hline
            2217 & [-1.7609  0.132   1.1581]e-14 & 3 & 3162 & 3162 & 0.9991 & 1 \\ \tabucline[1.5pt]{-}
        \end{tabu}
        \caption{Table title}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome !! thanks a lot for the prompt answer, just one thing ,the table doesn't have a title and auto numbering 

also , is it possible to make bold borders like the image,

Comment: @Farzad64 as you can see I edited my answer. Use a caption for the title and the tabu package for bold borders.

Comment: There is one thing dear Maarten , the table is still now exactly centered , like 1/4 th of the photo somehow goes to the right of the page